# Tool to convert formulas to C# code faster

Tags: c#, math, parser

I'm looking for a tool where I can simply type `b * (1 + k) ^ 9` and have `b * Math.Pow(1 + k, 9)` or even better `b * (float)Math.Pow(1 + k, 9)` as an output.

Sounds pretty easy?

Comment: Which OS? What cost? How could the converter know that there's a cast to float needed? What if a part of the expression causes an overflow? What operators need to be supported? Also n! (factorial), sin x, cos x? Do you also have x² and x³ or just x^2? Is division / or : or both? Sounds easy, but leaves many questions open.

Comment: @ThomasWeller anything I can run on Windows. x^n and basic arithmetic /*+- is enough, anything extra is.. extra ))

Comment: @ThomasWeller cast to `float` - as a developer of such tool (I'm not) I would make a checkbox to cast all return `double` values of `Math` methods to `float`.

Comment: Why do you want to convert them to C# code? Do you just want to evaluate them inside a C# program? Do you want to include them into your C# code? Something else?

Comment: @svick "Do you want to include them into your C# code?" - yes.

Comment: If you have somebody willing to type "b*(1+k)^9", why aren't they willing to type "b*Math.pow(1+k,9)"?

Comment: @IraBaxter they also type formulas for Excel, I need to convert them to code. because they are not programmers and can't verify it with compiler.

Comment: So  you want to accept an *Excel* style formula and produce a JavaScript equivelant?

Comment: @IraBaxter C#, not JS. They also provide human-style formulas so I can use either them or excel formulas.

Comment: So what you need is a language translator limited to Excel-style expressions as input, and producing C# expressions as output.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will find a tool that does exactly what you want off the shelf; the number of pairs of translations from computer language A to language B is big because there are lots of As and Bs, and you want a specific one.
(See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3455456/120163 for discussion of language translations)

OTOH, your translation is likely easier than most, being limited to just expressions.  You can probably do this with a [syntax-directed translator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax-directed_translation), e.g.:

1. Build a [recursive descent parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769) for the source language.
2. As the parser runs and does reductions, spit out the translation.

A more sophisticated variant:

1. Build [a recursive descent parser that builds a tree for the expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049751/constructing-an-abstract-syntax-tree-with-a-list-of-tokens/25106688#25106688)
2. Walk the tree in-order, and spit out the translation

Either one of these is probably pretty easy.

If you want a more structured attack, you can use a [Program transformation System (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation). These tools parse source according to a grammar, build a corresponding tree for the source, and then let you provide rewrite rules to map the original tree to a revised tree, and then can prettyprint the result.

Here's what this would look like with my PTS called DMS. This answer covers just your specific example and would need to be extended to handle the range of Excel tokens and formulas you want to handle; for instance, I'm not handling a floating point value (easy extension).

You'd need a lexer and parser for Excel formulas.
You need a lexer and a parser for C# expressions covering what you need
for Excel formulas.  With those two in hand, DMS will let us
write translation rules between the two.

Let's start with Excel.

Excel formula Lexer:

```
#skip "[\u0020]+" -- ignore whitespace
#token '+' "\+" -- plus operator
#token '*' "\*" -- times operator
#token '^' "\^" -- exponential operator
#token '(' "\(" -- left paren
#token ')' "\)" -- right paren
#token NUMBER [STRING] "[0-9]+"
  << (ConvertStringToToken ? 0 0)
     (= ?:Lexeme:String:Format 0) ; no quote on string
  >>
#token IDENTIFIER [STRING] "[a-z]"
  << (ConvertStringToToken ? 0 0) 
     (= ?:Lexeme:String:Format 0) ; no quote on string
  >>
```

Excel Formula parser:

```
Excel = expression ;
expression = product ;
expression = expression '+' product ;
product = power
product = product '*' power ;
power = primitive ;
power = power '^' primitive;
primitive = IDENTIFIER ;
primitive = NUMBER ;
primitive = '(' expression ')' ;
```

That's enough for DMS to parse your Excel formulas, and
automatically produce an AST.

We need the same for C# expressions:

C# formula Lexer (note that the terminal and nonterminal
names for C#, although nominally identical to those for Excel,
belong to C# [think of grammars as being separate namespaces]:

```
#skip "[\u0020\u000d\u000a]+" -- ignore whitespace and line breaks
#precomment "[\\][\\] ~[\u000d\uooa]+" -- single line comments
#token '+' "\+" -- plus operator
#token '*' "\*" -- times operator
#token '^' "\^" -- exponential operator
#token '.' "\." -- dot between identifiers in named entity
#token '(' "\(" -- left paren
#token ')' "\)" -- right paren
#token NATURAL [STRING] "[0-9]+"
  << (ConvertStringToToken ? 0 0)
     (= ?:Lexeme:String:Format 0) ; no quote on string
  >>
#token ID [STRING] "[a-z]+"
  << (ConvertStringToToken ? 0 0) 
     (= ?:Lexeme:String:Format 0) ; no quote on string
  >>
```

C# expression parser (good enough for this task)

```
CSharp = expression ;
expression = product ;
expression = expression '+' product ;
product = power
product = product '*' power ;
power = term ;
power = power '^' term;
term = named_entity ;
term = named_entity '(' expression ')' ; -- function call
term = NATURAL ;
term = '(' expression ')' ;
term = '( ID ')' term ; -- cast
named_entity = ID ;
named_entity = named_entity '.' ID ;
```

With this, DMS will parse simple C# expressions; we'll take advantage of that in right hand side of the rewrite rules below.  DMS will also prettyprint any parsed (or generated) C# using just this information; this will let us translate Excel to C#, and then pretty print the result.

I'm cheating slightly: I need prettyprinting rules for C#.  However, DMS will infer some set of such rules from just the grammar; since C# doesn't care about whitespace, the prettyprinting rules produced by DMS will produce a legal if not "pretty" text.  (One can add the prettyprinting rules to make it prettier, but that doesn't really affect our example).

OK, now we are ready to write our translation rules.
Such rules look like:

```
rule <rulename>( parameter: nonterminalA, ...) : nonterminalA -> nonterminalB
  = " <A_syntax_instance> " ->  "<B_syntax_replacement>"
```

for langauges A and B.

Fortunately the grammars are very similar, so the translation rules are easy and tend to map constructs in Excel to almost identical constructs in C#:

```
source domain Excel;  -- says to read left hand side of rules as 'excel syntax'
target domain Csharp; -- and right hand sides as 'CSharp syntax'

rule translate_IDENTIFIER(i: IDENTIFIER): IDENTIFIER -> ID
  "\i" -> " \i" ;  -- tells DMS to translate Excel node to C# node and copy the string
  -- fortunately for us, the CSharp ID names are a superset of what Excel offers,
  -- so we don't need any string hack to translate the identifiers

rule translate_NUMBER(n: NUMBER): NUMBER -> NATURAL
  = "\n" -> "\n" ; -- tells DMS to translate Excel NUMBER to CSharp Natural and copy the numeric value

rule translate_parentheses(e: expression): primtive -> term
  = " ( \e ) " -> " ( \e ) " ; -- these looks the same module syntax terms across the two langauge

rule translate_sum(e: expression, p: product): expression -> expression
  =  " \e + \p " -> " \e + \p ";

rule translate_product(p1: product, p2: power): product -> product
  =  " \p1 * \p2 " -> " \p1 * \p2 ";

rule translate_power(p1: power, p2: primitive): power -> power
  =  " \p1 ^ \p2 " -> " (float)Math.Pow(\p1,\p2)";
```

To understand these rules in detail, see [DMS Rewrite Rules](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html)

To use all this:

1. one gives DMS Refiner subtool the lexer/parser definition for Excel, the lexer/parser definition for CSharp, and the above ruleset.
2. The Refiner reads a file containing the Excel text, parses it according to Excel syntax ("Source domain Excel"), and builds an AST for the Excel code.
3. The Refiner applies the rules until no rule applies [this converts the Excel AST into a CSharp AST]
4. The refiner calls the CSharp prettyprinter on the resulting tree.

This should produce exactly what OP wants.

I haven't tested this, but it is pretty close to right.

For the size of task OP really wants to do, the syntax-directed scheme is probably less work; it is certainly a much "smaller" solution (DMS is a pretty big piece of machinery).  But if your translations start to get more complex, the syntax-directed approach gets out of hand fast, while the DMS path stays very effective.  YMMV.